# Hibernate - 1 Class 2 Tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple table and I want to store them in another table aswell (create a historic of users). Let's call it Users. I created a table exactly like Users (only different id name) called HISTORY_Users.

So I created the table and now I realize that I have 2 tables for 1 object. So how do I add my object only to the hist table?

**I dont want to add them at the same time. I want to add the user to the hist only when he deletes the accounts.**

I'm using Hibernate with xml mapping

```
 //when the user deletes the account I call this function and pass the User
  private static void addToHist(User User) {
      //how do I add only to HIST_Users table??
      Database.addToDatabase(user);

}


 //Save the object to the database
public static void addToDatabase(Object object) {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(object);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The obvious way would be to create another class exactly like Users but it doesn't seem right

Comment: If there isn't any privacy related requirements that require you to actually delete the data: Have you considered not actually deleting users from the table but instead just have a `boolean deleted` flag that you set to true to mark a user as deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better solution will be use the Hibernate Envers: http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/

You can configure when you want to put it into history: on create, update or delete.

Tables are created automatically, you need to add some annotations only like @Audited etc.